# Huffman encoding: The constructor HuffmanCoding(Map<Character,List<Boolean>>, List<Character>) is undefinedJava(134217858)

Tags: java, huffman-code

this is the code from Huffman.java

```
public static HuffmanCoding encode(String input) {
        char ch;
        Map<Character, List<Boolean>> inputData = buildCode(treeFromFreqTable(freqTable(input)));
        List<Character> mylist = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            ch = input.charAt(i);
            mylist.add(ch);
        }
        HuffmanCoding huffman = new HuffmanCoding(inputData, mylist);
        return huffman;
    }
```

this is the code from HuffmanCoding.java

```
public class HuffmanCoding implements Serializable {

    private final Map<Character, List<Boolean>> code; // The code.
    private final List<Boolean> data;                 // The data.

    public HuffmanCoding(Map<Character, List<Boolean>> code, List<Boolean> data) {
        this.code = code;
        this.data = data;
    }
```

it shows this error

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Character> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Boolean>
```

and

```
The constructor HuffmanCoding(Map<Character,List<Boolean>>, List<Character>) is undefinedJava(134217858)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear. `HuffmanCoding` wants a `List<Boolean>`, `encode` passes it a `List<Character>`.

Comment: how do i fix this? if im changing to boolean error is still occurring

Answer (score 0):

For this error:

incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Character> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.Boolean>

You are essentially inserting Characters into a list that accepts ONLY booleans values. Make sure whatever you’re inserting into the list of the correct type. (In this context make sure it’s true/false and no characters like ‘a’, ‘m’, ‘5’ etc).

For this error
The constructor HuffmanCoding(Map<Character,List>, List) is undefinedJava(134217858)

It’s telling you that you don’t have a constructor with the parameters you’re passing in. Create the following constructor to get rid of the problem:

Public HuffmanCoding(Map<Character, List> map, List characterList){}